# What replication_factor to use when using read replica clusters in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

How should I be reasoning about what values to set for `replication_factor` when running `yb-admin modify_placement_info` and `yb-admin add_read_replica_placement_info`? How does `replication_factor` relate to the number of yb-master/yb-tserver processes running?
Should the read replica cluster have the same RF as the primary cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of yb-tserver processes running on primary should be >= RF of primary.
The number of yb-tserver processes running on read-replica cluster should be >= RF of read-replica.
The number of yb-master processes should be = RF of primary (we don't use yb-master processes in read-replica clusters today).

For DDL, the requirements currently are the above.

For DML/queries... you can be temporarily down to, say, 2 nodes on a RF=3 cluster... you still have a quorum and can make progress.

First, you need to ask the question what replication factor you want in primary (that should be an odd number - because of quorum protocol) typically 3 for most production deployments, and sometimes people go with 5. But 3 is generally the most common.
For read-replica cluster, those don't need to be odd (this is not quorum-based).. the RF there can be 1, 2, 3, etc. It is perfectly ok to have RF=2 or rf=1 in a read-replica cluster and three nodes there.

Similarly, it is perfectly ok to have RF=3 on the primary cluster and the number of nodes is 4 or 5.